# How to read a text file to R selectively?

Tags: sql, r

I used the function read.csv2.sql but an error is returned:

```
> mySql <- "SELECT * from file WHERE Date = '1/2/2007' OR Date = '2/2/2007'"
> myFile <- "household_power_consumption.txt"
> myData <- read.csv2.sql(myFile,mySql)
```

Loading required package: **tcltk**

Error in sqliteExecStatement(con, statement, bind.data) : 
RS-DBI driver: (error in statement: no such column: Date)

The thing is that there is a Date column in the file, so please who can tell me what's wrong here?

Comment: What package does the function `read.csv2.sql` come from?

Comment: Also, can you show the first 4 lines or so from your `household_power_consumption.txt` file?

Comment: Try this read.csv2.sql(myFile,mySql,header = TRUE, sep = ",")

Comment: @MrFlick,it's from the package "sqldf", and the first lines are like this:  Date     Time Global_active_power Global_reactive_power Voltage Global_intensity
1 1/2/2007 00:00:00               0.326                 0.128  243.15              1.4
2 1/2/2007 00:01:00               0.326                 0.130  243.32              1.4

Comment: @Aashu,thank u for your help, I tried your method but there is still an error get returned. Actually I tried the function"read.csv.sql" and this one works.Really dont understand why...

Answer (score 1):

`read.csv2.sql` assumes that the character separating each field is `;`. `read.sqv.sql` assume that the character separating each field is `,`. From the sample lines you posted, it appears that you just have a space between each field. If that's the case you should set `sep=" "` when you call the function.